# Using Google Maps API on Single page application - Error using multiple times the api

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I have an angular WebApp in which I use the google Map API. It is loaded in the html view. On click the states changes to another page and loads the map. It is working well for the first time. When I go back to the loading page my console says: You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors. And when i load the map again, some unexpected errors are happening.

So my question: Is it possible to reset the google Maps API so that it refreshes everytime i go back? Or can i delete the instance or what should i do?

I'm using the angular google maps directive: https://angular-ui.github.io/ and implementing it with:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXX" type="text/javascript">
```

On the page who is loading it.

The maps page is loaded with resolving the 'uiGmapgoogle-maps' directive.

I'm using the inline javascript cause i could not figure out how to pass an api key to the directive settings. And I load it before the google maps page so, the maps loads well.

State first page:

```
.state('apps.vermittlungDetail', {
                  url: '/vermittlung/detail/:taskID',
                  templateUrl: 'tpl/apps_vermittlung_detail.html',
                  controller: 'XeditableCtrl',
                  resolve: load( ['ui.select','toaster','js/app/globalServices/global-services.js','js/app/vermittlung/newTask-service.js','js/controllers/bootstrap.js','js/app/vermittlung/vermittlung-detail.js','js/app/annulation/annulation-service.js','js/app/smsTool/smsTool-service.js','js/app/emailMami/emailmami-service.js'  ,'js/app/vermittlung/vermittlung-service.js', 'smart-table','xeditable','js/controllers/xeditable.js', 'moment'])
              })
```

State second page (the map)

```
.state('apps.vermittlungGoogleMap', {
                  url: '/vermittlungMap',
                  templateUrl: 'tpl/apps_vermittlung_googlemap.html',
                  resolve: load( ['uiGmapgoogle-maps','toaster','js/app/vermittlung/vermittlung-detail.js', 'js/app/vermittlung/vermittlung-service.js'])

              })
```

HTML second page

```
<div ng-controller="vermittlungDetailCtrl"> <!--SET CONTROLLER-->

    <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
      <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" options="markers.options" click="onClickMarker">
      </ui-gmap-markers>

      <ui-gmap-window options="windowOptions" show="showWindow" coords="windowData.model" closeClick="closeClick()">
          <div>
          <div class="m-b-sm">{{currentMarkerTitle}}<br>{{currentMarkerPhone}}</div>
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" ng-click="$parent.sendMamiSMS($parent.tasktosend,$parent.currentMarkerPhone,$parent.currentMarkerTitle)">SMS senden</button>
          </div>
            </ui-gmap-window>

    </ui-gmap-google-map>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set the controller on your state, not your template.

```
.state('apps.vermittlungGoogleMap', {
              url: '/vermittlungMap',
              controller: 'vermittlungDetailCtrl',
              templateUrl: 'tpl/apps_vermittlung_googlemap.html',
              resolve: load( ['uiGmapgoogle-maps','toaster','js/app/vermittlung/vermittlung-detail.js', 'js/app/vermittlung/vermittlung-service.js'])

          })
```

Then stop importing GoogleMaps like this

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXX" type="text/javascript">
```

Angular Google Maps already does it.

To manipulate the map and insert your API key, take a look [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/GoogleMapApi).

Comment: Thanks! Now it is working! But I still get the "no api key" error in the console. well the map is working without but how can i configure it? I do not understand clearly where i have to put the config. It seems that it isnt loading. i think. Do I need to create a config file and layzload it as well?

Comment: Well actualy it isnt working. I was checking an old version which was working. I'm not able to load the apiKey over configuration as in the docs. it it nos loading.

Comment: You should insert it after the module declaration, like this:
`angular
        .module('yourModule')
        .config(config);

    config.$inject = ['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider'];

    function config(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider){
        uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
            key: 'YOUR_KEY',
            libraries: 'LIBRARIES_YOU_NEED'
        });
    };
`

Answer (score 1):

The answer from mcrvaz solved my problem. I removed the inline javascript file. And loaded it uiGmapgogole map Instance in the controller. Like in the docs.

```
.controller("someController", function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {
// Do stuff with your $scope.
// Note: Some of the directives require at least something to be defined originally!
// e.g. $scope.markers = []

// uiGmapGoogleMapApi is a promise.
// The "then" callback function provides the google.maps object.
uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {

});
```

});

I was missing putting "uiGmapGoogleMapApi" in the controller head.